# Can an RCD do the job of an ordinary fuse?

Tags: short-circuit, fuses, rcd

Suppose we have a short circuit somewhere in a house. Does a residual-current device (RCD) stop the current in this situation exactly as an ordinary fuse does? or it's not reliable for this?

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for a particular RCD in mind, or is this a conceptual question? I have seen devices that are marketed as RCD, and engineered+certified to interrupt on both overcurrent and residual current/tiny ground fault.

Comment: @nanofarad, thanks for the comment. My question is not about a particular RCD.

Comment: No problem; added as a full answer to which I can add further details as needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An RCD/GFCI alone does not do the job of an ordinary fuse, which is to interrupt an overcurrent condition; rather its purpose is to detect imbalances in current that suggest dangerous leakage or ground faults.

However, it is common to see devices which are marketed, engineered, and certified to have both RCD and overcurrent protection functions. An example is the GFCI circuit breakers for the North American market which have both an overcurrent and an RCD trip, and are installed in home distribution panels similarly to traditional circuit breakers. Likewise, in the European market, such a device is called an RCBO.

Comment: To OP: In my house (Ireland) I have a 63 A incoming fuse, a 40 A RCD feeding all the sockets and 20 A MCB on each socket circuit. The RCD will trip on overcurrent but the 20 A breaker should trip first to localise the fault to just one circuit.

Comment: Although as I have discovered, a large overcurrent situation does not guarantee that a lower-rated breaker will trip before a higher-rated one, although they usually do.

Comment: The combined RCD and breaker is known in Europe as an RCBO.

Answer (score 0):

Traditional Residual Current Devices (RCD) are only check is current fllowing to the device equal to the Current fllowing out from the device. If any imbalance Occured it simply activate a magnet and it cause to trip the device. It does not have any over current protection.
But some modern RCD having a over current/ over load protection mechanisam in built.